# How can I update my Object with selected inputs in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have code like this

```
{"xyz":[{"a":1,"b":"","c":""}],
"pqr":["l","m"],
"abc":["1234","5678"]}

<div ng-model="item" ng-repeat="product in xyz">
    <div>{product.a}</div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="value in pqr">{{value}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select>
            <option ng-repeat="number in abc">{{number}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to update my object on changing the values in dropdowns and update the onject "xyz"!

Comment: your markup is very vague! why put select tags in `.. ng-repeat="product in xyz">`?

Comment: For every product, I have to set its properties which are in arrays "pqr" and "abc" and send the updated object to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

you should define model for select tag.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
    $scope.data = 
        {
      
         "xyz":[{"a":1,"b":"","c":""}],
         "pqr":["l","m"],
         "abc":["1234","5678"]
       }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data.xyz">
    <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">{{v}}</div>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="model1" ng-options="v1 as v1 for v1 in data.pqr" ng-change="value.b = model1">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select ng-model="model2" ng-options="number as number for number in data.abc" ng-change="value.c = model2">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `ng-repeat` on `<option>` use `ng-options` instead. Documentation and examples can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

As for your code, you will need to bind the select to your object:

```
<select ng-model="product.a" ...> //or which ever property you are trying to update
```